Android CameraX FPS > 30 causes image crop
I have an application which uses CameraX API with Preview and Analyzer Use cases.
I'm setting the desired FPS using the Camera2Interop.Extender() and setting the CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE option to Range(60,60) for example
val previewBuilder = Preview.Builder()
    .setTargetResolution(currentRes)
...
val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
    .requireLensFacing(cameraLens)
    .build()
val fps = ConfigurationService.fps.toInt() // 60
val frameDuration = 1000000000L/fps // 1666666
if (cameraSelector.lensFacing!! == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
    Camera2Interop.Extender(previewBuilder)
        .setCaptureRequestOption(
            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE,
            Range(fps, fps))
        .setCaptureRequestOption(
            CaptureRequest.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION,
            frameDuration
        )
}

Then setting up the preview and the analyzer
val preview = previewBuilder.build()

val analysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
    .setTargetResolution(currentRes)
    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
    .setOutputImageFormat(ConfigurationService.cameraInputType)
    .setImageQueueDepth(countOfCores)
    .build()

analysis.setAnalyzer(Executors.newWorkStealingPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()), analyzer)

val useCaseGroup = UseCaseGroup.Builder()
    .addUseCase(preview)
    .addUseCase(analysis)
    .build()
try {
    cameraProvider?.unbindAll()
    camera = cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(
        context as LifecycleOwner,
        cameraSelector,
        useCaseGroup
    )
    previewView.implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.PERFORMANCE
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(
        previewView.surfaceProvider
    )
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e("CameraClassificationWrapper", "Use case binding failed", e)
}

The issue I'm facing is that when the FPS is set to anything higher than 30, the incoming images are still of the correct width/height (1280x720) in this case, but it seems to be cropped from part of the sensor, causing the image to appear "zoomed in". For less than 30 the images seems to be correct.
Since I'm using the analyzer to do real-world measurements using calibrated camera for specific resolutions, I need the images to match what I calibrated with.
I saw several mentions of such issue for other platforms or just for general use case.
I know Camera2 has the CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession way, and I would have used it except that the entire application already uses CameraX and I would really like to avoid replacing the entire camera backend
Is there anyway of getting full resolution (up to 1080p) in 60 FPS using CameraX?

Have you tried setting the FPS value to Preview.Builder#setTargetFrameRate API as well?
CameraX chooses stream specs according to the bound use cases and the FPS. So the selected stream spec may be returned according to 30 FPS and has a different resolution which is not matching with the 60 FPS being set.

Note that the 60 FPS may not be supported in all devices and CameraX may not respect the value then. But the issue might be solved in supported cases at least and give more insight on the problem.

By the way, it seems like CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession is mainly for >= 120 FPS according to doc, usually for use cases like slow-mo vids. If you do require it for your use cases, consider creating a feature request to the CameraX team at their issue tracker with your use cases and the team can consider it further.

Does the device actually claim to support 60fps?  That is, does AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES list [60,60]?
If it does not, attempting to set it anyway may result in unexpected behavior such as what you're seeing.
If it is listed, then unfortunately the device you're testing has a bug; the FOV should not change based on requested frame rate.
As a side note, setting CaptureRequest.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION does nothing if you leave CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE to the default ON. It's only effective if autoexposure is disabled.  So you might as well remove it to simplify your code. Conversely, if you set AE_MODE to OFF then CONTROL_TARGET_FPS_RANGE will do nothing instead.
